Can non metals react with bases and acids
I am confused about whether non metals can react with bases and acids. I tried to look it up but the only thing that came up was non metallic oxides. So for example can Carbon react with KOH or HCl?

There are isotropic and anisotropic wet etches for silicon.

Depends, but carbon in particular is unreactive. You wouldn't think diamond would dissolve in your stomach, wouldn't you?

But, first, define a ‘non metal’ for clarity.

There is a part of chemistry that can be described by simple rules. It is taught in schools. Then there is a part that isn't.

Fluorine is not metal and reacts with both bases and acids ( and near everything).

Of course they can. Why do you think they cannot?

Here is an example: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118485/reactivity-of-boron-towards-acids

Of course. Why not?
$$\ce{3I2 + 10HNO3 -> 6HIO3 + 10NO + 2H2O}$$
$$\ce{3I2 + 6OH- -> IO3- + 5I-+ 3H2O}$$
