# Balancing OH- reduction to H2

Tags: redox

I have to balance the following redox equation:

$\ce{B + NaOH -> NaBO2 + H2 + Na2O}$

Here I identified B as the species which undrgoes oxidation and wrote the oxidation half-reaction:

$\ce{4OH- + B -> BO2- + 2H2O + 3e-}$

The only element whose oxidation number is reduced is H from +1 in $\ce{OH-}$ to 0 in $\ce{H2}$. So the (unbalanced) reduction half-reaction should be something like:

$\ce{2e- + 2OH- -> H2}$

How does one balance that?

Comment: If you write NaOH as OH- why not towrite Na2O as O^2- ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Balancing reaction between copper and nitric acid given the ratio of formed nitrogen oxides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150262/balancing-reaction-between-copper-and-nitric-acid-given-the-ratio-of-formed-nitr)

Comment: I think it could be: 2$\ce{B}$ + 6$\ce{NaOH}$ $\rightarrow$ 2$\ce{NaBO2}$ + 3$\ce{H2}$ + 2 $\ce{Na2O}$

Comment: Per this source: "Boron reacts with fused sodium hydroxide to form sodium borate and hydrogen."  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67434/reaction-of-boron-with-alkali

Comment: It would be rather Na3B3O6, as metaborate is a cyclical trimer with alternating O and BO-

Comment: Your last equation can be balanced by writing : $\ce{2 e- + 2 OH^- -> H2 + 2 O^{2-}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Poutnik in the comments I considered $\ce{O2-}$ in the reduction half reaction which then became:

$\ce{2OH- + 2e- -> H2 + 2O^2-}$

After multiplying each half-reaction by the number of electrons exchanged by the other one and adding back the spectator ions the balanced equation becomes:

$\ce{14NaOH + 2B -> 2NaBO2 + 3H2 + 6Na2O + 4H2O}$

Comment: Subtract from it reaction $\ce{8 NaOH -> 4 Na2O + 4 H2O}$ that does not happen in a condensed phase and you will get $\ce{6 NaOH + 2 B -> 2 NaBO2 + 3 H2 + 2 Na2O}$